# Is replayLast possible in ReactiveCocoa 4?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

In RAC2 you could tack `replayLast` onto a signal to make a signal that, when subscribed to, would immediately send the last value and all future values. Is such a thing possible with SignalProducers in RAC4? I don't see any `replayLast`.

Comment: Look at `buffer` -- it's definitely possible, but not quite as ergonomic.

Comment: `buffer` is a class method on SignalProducer that basically gives you a Subject that you can manually feed things into.  I can't think of a way to use it for an existing signal unless I do something like subscribe to the events of the signal and `sendNext` each item to the observer. I can't bring myself to do that...

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that what you want to do is better expressed with the new [`PropertyType`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift). Otherwise, I am trying to include [`replayLazily`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/2639) in RAC 4.

Comment: I'll take a look at `PropertyType`. Thanks.